# igraph module of python produces more vertices

Tags: python, igraph

I am trying to use igraph module of python. When i type

```
g = Graph()
g.add_vertices(3)
print(g)
```

The output is as follows

```
Undirected graph (|V| = 4, |E| = 0)
```

which means one more than what I asked for.

The tutorial here says different
[python igraph tutorial](http://hal.elte.hu/~nepusz/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Comment: Why don't you report this as a bug then? (It seems to work for me with the latest version, so don't forget to include your igraph version in the bug report.)

Comment: Works for me as well; igraph 0.6.5 with Python 2.7.2. Chances are that you are using a far outdated version of the Python module which used to create a graph with a single vertex and no edges when the `Graph()` constructor was called. Try using `Graph(0)` instead of `Graph()` - this specifies the number of vertices in the initial graph explicitly.